# Start a service/foregroundService is bringing app to front if it is in background

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

A simple call to

`Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);`

is bringing the app to front if it's in the background, nothing happens if the app were closed. I want to avoid this behavior but, i do not know how to do it.
It happened on android **O** and **P**. 
I've setted up the `alarmManager`to wake up my app at specific time, then a `pendingIntent` starts an `Activity` (it does not show anything in the screen) and it checks the received action from the `Intent` to determine the action to be performed. I have 2 Services in my app and both of them bring app to front everytime they're waked up, this is annoying to user.

Comment: restrictions has been added from android O thats the reason .

Comment: I don't think this is due to Android OS behavior, I think your own code is somehow starting the Activity at the time the Service starts. Consider dumping the result of `Activity.getIntent()` in `Activity.onCreate()`, and determine whether it is a launcher Intent, or your `alarmManager` Intent.

Comment: @greeble31 services behavior has been changed from Android O lucky enogh for the OP his app behaves differetly only on devices running android O and above

Comment: @Jeeva It did indeed change in Oreo, but not in a way that causes this problem. Oreo requires the app to be on the temporary whitelist; otherwise, Service creation fails and an exception gets thrown. What the OP seems to be describing is an Activity returning to the foreground, unprompted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing `PendingIntent.getActivity()` by `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` while creating the `PendingIntent`that would be triggered by `AlarmManager`. Here is the code:

```
      private PendingIntent getNotifyIntent() {
         Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(mContext, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
         return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, notifyIntent, 0);
}
```

I already used this code before (`PendingIntent.getActivity()`) but i never saw the app comes to screen before. The activity I used was totally transparent and invisible, it did not put a layout on the screen. I used it because for some reason using Broadcast was not working. But now the application was opening, I presume it was because the transparent activity opened would check what should be done and closed, calling the activity before it to be displayed on the screen.

> Resuming:  the problem wasn't the service itself but, the way i was setting up the `AlarmManager`

Tank u All by the help!

Answer (score -1):

> Prior to Android 8.0, the usual way to create a foreground service was
>   to create a background service, then promote that service to the
>   foreground. With Android 8.0, there is a complication; the system
>   doesn't allow a background app to create a background service. For
>   this reason, Android 8.0 introduces the new method
>   startForegroundService() to start a new service in the foreground.
>   After the system has created the service, the app has five seconds to
>   call the service's startForeground() method to show the new service's
>   user-visible notification. If the app does not call startForeground()
>   within the time limit, the system stops the service and declares the
>   app to be ANR.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47611385/6059583
Follow this link which shows how to show notiication to run service i background

Comment: My problem isn't  that  service does not start, it starts normally, the problem is that when service starts if the app is open in background it is bringed to front. I just need to run my foreground services without automatically show my app to user if it's open in background

Comment: then u need to show a notiication to show that ur service is running in background

Comment: I do, I  start a service with    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);    and inside the NotificationService i create a notification and call startForeground. Everything works correctly but if the app is already open in background it is showed to user, this is the problem, i don't want the app come from background and be showed to user just because i started a service.

Comment: -1 This appears to be instruction on how to start a foreground service, but does not address the OP's problem: That the app is resuming at unexpected times.

Comment: @greeble31 thats why i mentioned the link from android services which say services behaviour is completely changed