# Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION

Tags: java, android

I have an application for recording a screen, it does not work on android version 10. As I understand it, this is due to privacy changes in force in Android 10. I added the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />` to my manifest file, added the `android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"` tag to the service and call the `startForeground()` method

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "333")
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Record")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        Notification notification = builder.build();

        startForeground(123, notification);
```

before calling the `.getMediaProjection()` method, but my application still throws an error exactly

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.screen_recording, PID: 9572
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.screen_recording.service.RecordService@bb31978 with Intent { cmp=com.example.screen_recording/.service.RecordService (has extras) }: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:231)
        at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:58)
        at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.java:104)
        at com.example.screen_recording.service.RecordService.onStartRecord(RecordService.java:117)
        at com.example.screen_recording.service.RecordService.onStartCommand(RecordService.java:106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.media.projection.MediaProjectionManagerService$MediaProjection.start(MediaProjectionManagerService.java:476)
        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaProjection.java:135)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

Here is the service code

```
public class RecordService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    SharedPreferences p;
    WindowManager window;

    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private boolean isRecord = false;
    private String videoUri = "";

    private MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager;
    private MediaProjection mediaProjection;
    private VirtualDisplay virtualDisplay;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    private int mScreenDensity;
    private static int DISPLAY_WIDTH;
    private static int DISPLAY_HEIGHT;
    private int resultCode;
    private Intent resultData;

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "333")
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Record")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        Notification notification = builder.build();

        startForeground(123, notification);

        p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        window.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        mScreenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
        DISPLAY_WIDTH = metrics.widthPixels;
        DISPLAY_HEIGHT = metrics.heightPixels;


        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (intent.getAction() == null) {
            resultCode = intent.getIntExtra("code", 1337);
            resultData = intent.getParcelableExtra("data");
        }

        onStartRecord();
        return (START_NOT_STICKY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        onStopRecord();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void onStartRecord() {
        mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, resultData);

        int quality = p.getInt("quality", 1080);
        boolean micro = p.getBoolean("micro", false);
        int fps = p.getInt("FPS", 60);

        initRecorder(quality, micro, fps);
        virtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();

        isRecord = true;
        p.edit().putBoolean("isRecord", isRecord).apply();
        mediaRecorder.start();
    }

    private void onStopRecord() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.reset();

        stopRecordScreen();


        isRecord = false;
        p.edit().putBoolean("isRecord", isRecord).apply();
    }

    private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay() {
        return mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainFragment", DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, mScreenDensity,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                mediaRecorder.getSurface(), null, null);
    }

    private void initRecorder(int QUALITY, boolean isMicro, int fps) {
        try {
            int bitrateVideo = 0;

            switch (QUALITY) {
                case 1080:
                    bitrateVideo = 7000000;
                    break;
                case 720:
                    bitrateVideo = 4000000;
                    break;
                default:
                    bitrateVideo = 2000000;
                    break;
            }

            if (isMicro) {
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            }

            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

            if (isMicro) {
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16 * 44100);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            }


            videoUri = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
                    + new StringBuilder("/FreeRecord_").append(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")
                    .format(new Date())).append(".mp4").toString();

            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoUri);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(bitrateVideo);
            mediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(fps);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(fps);

            int rotation = window.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
            mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecordScreen() {
        if (virtualDisplay == null) {
            return;
        }
        virtualDisplay.release();
        destroyMediaProject();
    }

    private void destroyMediaProject() {
        if (mediaProjection != null) {
            mediaProjection.stop();
            mediaProjection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a `foreground service` with the notification channel.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // create notification channel
            new NotificationManager(this,11111);
            // Create notification builder.
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1212, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NotificationManager.CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
            builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
            builder.setContentTitle(getString(title));
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            startForeground(100000, notification);
            Log.d(TAG,"Start foreground service");
        }
```

Find the below link to start service in `foreground` for your reference.
[Oreo - Starting a service in the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611123/oreo-starting-a-service-in-the-foreground)

Comment: @ziotyr: Did you get this working? Can you please share the ScreenCaptureManager class? Github proj will be great too.

Comment: Yes, it is working. let me know if you facing any issues regarding this.

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276730/media-projections-require-a-foreground-service-of-type-serviceinfo-foreground-sel and still doesn't seems to work. Is is mandatory to add mediaprojection to the service.

Comment: @user2801184, Yes, it is mandatory to use the forgroundType in the manifest. Have you created the service as foreground service that you have declared in the manifest as forgroundType:mediaprojection?

Comment: please send the service class code or logcat error message if possible.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/ for C# please follow this before creating a service.

Comment: @user2801184, use this document as a reference to create the foreground service, it won't work with normal service. you have to make the service as foreground service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services