# XAM.Forms app with MediaProjections error 'Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm at a loss, had to update our app to target Android 13. Now our screen capturing is no longer working.  I didn't write this section of the code, so I don't completely understand what it is doing.  The app crashes with `Java.Lang.SecurityException: 'Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION'` when it gets to this line:

```
PermissionValues.mediaProjection = PermissionValues.mediaProjectionManager.GetMediaProjection(PermissionValues.resultCode, PermissionValues.resultData);
```

I've read i need to add the service to the androidmanifest.xml which i did inside the application node:

```
<service
     android:name="CameraService"
     android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"
     android:exported="false">
</service>
```

Also, I saw to add the permission to androidmanifest, so I did that `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`

Here is the class that throws the error:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Hardware.Display;
using Android.Media;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Util;
using CustomRenderer.Droid;
using Android.Content;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using Java.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Hardware;
using Java.Nio;

namespace myApp.Droid
{
    // Provides UI for the screen capture
    public class CameraService : ScreenshotService
    {
        private const string TAG = "ScreenCaptureFragment";

        private const string STATE_RESULT_CODE = "result_code";
        private const string STATE_RESULT_DATA = "result_data";
        private const int REQUEST_MEDIA_PROJECTION = 1;
        private int screenDensity;
        private Surface surface;
        private VirtualDisplay virtualDisplay;
        private Android.Views.View surfaceView;
        MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
        public static MediaRecorder CameraRecorder;
        public static Camera camera;
        private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
        string path;
        string screenpath;
        public static bool isrecording;
        int filenumber;
        public static MediaMuxer mMuxer;
        public static MediaCodec mVideoEncoder;
        private MediaCodec.BufferInfo mVideoBufferInfo;
        Surface mInputSurface;
        private int mTrackIndex = -1;
        bool mmuxerstarted = false;
        long TIMEOUT_USEC = 100000;
        public static bool enc_outputDone = false;
        long mFakePts;
        private static string VIDEO_MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";

        //these are made into member objects of class to maintain reference during the camera recording process
        Surface sf;
        Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture sft;

        private Handler mDrainHandler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);

        public void StartScreenCapture()
        {
            CameraPreviewRenderer.cameraPreview.Preview.StopPreview();
            CameraPreviewRenderer.cameraPreview.Preview.Release();

            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            var metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
            screenDensity = (int)metrics.DensityDpi;

            surfaceView = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window.DecorView.RootView;

            initCameraRecorder();

            initRecorder();
            SetUpMediaProjection();
            SetUpVirtualDisplay();
            //mMediaRecorder.Start();

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never);

        }

        public async void StartAll()
        {
            CameraRecorder.Start();

            await Task.Delay(500);

            mVideoEncoder.Start();
            drainEncoder();
        }

        private void SetUpMediaProjection()
        {
            
            PermissionValues.mediaProjection = PermissionValues.mediaProjectionManager.GetMediaProjection(PermissionValues.resultCode, PermissionValues.resultData);
            System.Console.WriteLine("result code " + PermissionValues.resultCode);
            System.Console.WriteLine("result data " + PermissionValues.resultData);
        }

        private void SetUpVirtualDisplay()
        {
            Log.Info(TAG, "Setting up a VirtualDisplay: " + surfaceView.Width + "x" + surfaceView.Height + " (" + screenDensity + ")");
            virtualDisplay = PermissionValues.mediaProjection.CreateVirtualDisplay("ScreenCapture",
                480, 640, screenDensity, 0, mInputSurface, null, null);

            //this is for surface recording using mediarecorder
            /*Log.Info(TAG, "Setting up a VirtualDisplay: " + surfaceView.Width + "x" + surfaceView.Height + " (" + screenDensity + ")");
            virtualDisplay = PermissionValues.mediaProjection.CreateVirtualDisplay("ScreenCapture",
                surfaceView.Width, surfaceView.Height, screenDensity,
                (DisplayFlags)VirtualDisplayFlags.AutoMirror, mMediaRecorder.Surface, null, null);*/
        }

        public List<string> StopScreenCapture()
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Default);

            System.Console.WriteLine("stopping screen capture");
            isrecording = false;

            //mMediaRecorder.Stop();

            /*if (mVideoEncoder != null)
            {
                mVideoEncoder.Stop();
            }

            if (mMuxer != null)
            {
                mMuxer.Stop();
                mMuxer.Release();
                mMuxer = null;
            }*/

            if (mInputSurface != null)
            {
                mInputSurface.Release();
            }

            if (PermissionValues.mediaProjection != null)
            {
                PermissionValues.mediaProjection.Stop();
                PermissionValues.mediaProjection = null;
            }

            mmuxerstarted = false;
            mVideoBufferInfo = null;

            virtualDisplay.Release();

            var pathlist = new List<string>();
            pathlist.Add(path);
            pathlist.Add(screenpath);

            return pathlist;
        }

        private void initRecorder()
        {
            try
            {
                isrecording = true;
                screenpath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-M-d--HH-mm-ss") + "videoscreen.mp4";
                mVideoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                int frameRate = 10;

                System.Console.WriteLine("surface width " + surfaceView.Width);
                System.Console.WriteLine("surface height " + surfaceView.Height);

                MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.CreateVideoFormat(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE, 480, 640);
                format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyColorFormat, 2130708361);
                format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyBitRate, 4000000); // 6Mbps
                format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyFrameRate, frameRate);
                format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyCaptureRate, frameRate);
                format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyRepeatPreviousFrameAfter, 1000000 / frameRate);
                format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyIFrameInterval, 5);
                format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyMaxInputSize, 0);

                //mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(screenpath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MuxerOutputMpeg4);
                mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(screenpath, Android.Media.MuxerOutputType.Mpeg4);


                if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop) //Android.OS.Build.VERSION_CODES.Lollipop
                {
                    mVideoEncoder = MediaCodec.CreateByCodecName("OMX.google.h264.encoder");
                    //mVideoEncoder.Configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.ConfigureFlagEncode);
                    mVideoEncoder.Configure(format, null, null, MediaCodecConfigFlags.Encode);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("second option");
                    mVideoEncoder = MediaCodec.CreateEncoderByType(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE);
                    //mVideoEncoder.Configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.ConfigureFlagEncode);
                    mVideoEncoder.Configure(format, null, null, MediaCodecConfigFlags.Encode);
                }

                mInputSurface = mVideoEncoder.CreateInputSurface();
                //mVideoEncoder.Start();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(@"ERROR initrecorder {0}", ex.Message);
            }


            /*
            try
            {
            //uses mediarecorder for surface. Cannot use 2 mediarecorders at same time
                mMediaRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Default);
                mMediaRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Surface);
            
                screenpath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-M-d--HH-mm-ss") + "videoscreen.mp4";
                mMediaRecorder.SetOutputFile(screenpath);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("path " + screenpath);
               
                //Customise your profile based on a pre-existing profile
                CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.Get(CamcorderQuality.Low);
                profile.FileFormat = OutputFormat.Mpeg4;
                profile.VideoCodec = VideoEncoder.H264;
            
                // Apply to MediaRecorder
                mMediaRecorder.SetProfile(profile);
                mMediaRecorder.Prepare();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
            }*/
        }

        private void drainEncoder()
        {

            var countdownseconds = System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);

            Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(countdownseconds, () =>
            {

                try
                {
                    if (isrecording)
                    {
                        var bufferIndex = mVideoEncoder.DequeueOutputBuffer(mVideoBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);

                        if (!mmuxerstarted && bufferIndex == -2)
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Starting muxer");
                            MediaFormat newFormat = mVideoEncoder.OutputFormat;

                            mTrackIndex = mMuxer.AddTrack(newFormat);

                            mMuxer.Start();
                            mmuxerstarted = true;

                        }
                        
                        if ((mVideoBufferInfo.Flags & MediaCodecBufferFlags.CodecConfig) != 0) //if ((mVideoBufferInfo.Flags & MediaCodec.BufferFlagCodecConfig) != 0)
                        {
                            // The codec config data was pulled out and fed to the muxer when we got
                            // the INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED status.  Ignore it.
                            System.Console.WriteLine("ignoring BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG" + mVideoBufferInfo.Size);
                            mVideoBufferInfo.Size = 0;
                        }
                        else if (bufferIndex < 0)
                        {
                            // not sure what's going on, ignore it
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("start bufferindex " + bufferIndex);

                            ByteBuffer encodedData = mVideoEncoder.GetOutputBuffer(bufferIndex);

                            if (mmuxerstarted && isrecording)
                            {
                                System.Console.WriteLine("bufferindex " + bufferIndex);
                                System.Console.WriteLine("bufferindexinfo " + mVideoBufferInfo.Size);

                                encodedData.Position(mVideoBufferInfo.Offset);

                                System.Console.WriteLine("s1 " + mVideoBufferInfo.Offset + " & " + mVideoBufferInfo.Size + " " + encodedData.Capacity());

                                encodedData.Limit(mVideoBufferInfo.Offset + mVideoBufferInfo.Size);

                                //mVideoBufferInfo.PresentationTimeUs = mFakePts;

                                //mFakePts += 1000000L / 10;

                                System.Console.WriteLine("trackindex " + mTrackIndex);

                                mMuxer.WriteSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mVideoBufferInfo);
                            }

                            mVideoEncoder.ReleaseOutputBuffer(bufferIndex, false);
                        }
                    }
                    if (isrecording)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    mMuxer.Stop();
                    mMuxer.Release();
                    mVideoEncoder.Stop();
                    mVideoEncoder.Release();

                    System.Console.WriteLine(@"ERROR drain encoder {0}", ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        private int findFrontFacingCamera()
        {
            int cameraId = -1;
            // Search for the front facing camera
            int numberOfCameras = Camera.NumberOfCameras;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)
            {
                Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                Camera.GetCameraInfo(i, info);
                if (info.Facing == CameraFacing.Front) //Camera.CameraInfo.CameraFacingFront
                {
                    cameraId = i;
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Front Camera " + cameraId);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return cameraId;
        }

        private void initCameraRecorder()
        {
            try
            {
                camera = Camera.Open(1);
                camera.Unlock();
                CameraRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

                //sets the orientation
                var windowManager = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
                switch (windowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation)
                {
                    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0:
                        CameraRecorder.SetOrientationHint(270);
                        break;
                    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90:
                        CameraRecorder.SetOrientationHint(0);
                        break;
                    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270:
                        CameraRecorder.SetOrientationHint(180);
                        break;
                }

                CameraRecorder.SetCamera(camera);
                CameraRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
                CameraRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
                sft = new Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture(0);
                sf = new Surface(sft);
                CameraRecorder.SetPreviewDisplay(sf);

                path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-M-d--HH-mm-ss") + "video.mp4";

                CameraRecorder.SetOutputFile(path);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("path " + path);

                CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.Get(findFrontFacingCamera(), CamcorderQuality.Q480p);
                profile.Quality = CamcorderQuality.Q480p;
                profile.VideoFrameRate = 25; // can't be lower than that or new android devices won't be able to support
                profile.FileFormat = OutputFormat.ThreeGpp;
                profile.VideoCodec = VideoEncoder.Default;
                
                // Apply to MediaRecorder
                CameraRecorder.SetProfile(profile);
                CameraRecorder.Prepare();
            }

            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
                camera.Release();
            }
        }

        private Android.Util.Size ChooseVideoSize(Android.Util.Size[] choices)
        {
            foreach (Android.Util.Size size in choices)
            {
                if (size.Width == size.Height * 4 / 3 && size.Width <= 1000)
                    return size;
            }
            Log.Error(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable video size");
            return choices[choices.Length - 1];
        }

        private MediaCodec configDecoder(MediaFormat format)
        {
            if (format == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            MediaCodec codec;
            string mime = format.GetString(MediaFormat.KeyMime);
            MediaCodecList list = new MediaCodecList(MediaCodecListKind.RegularCodecs);
            MediaCodecInfo[] infos = list.GetCodecInfos();

            foreach (MediaCodecInfo info in infos)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("info name " + info.Name);
                System.Console.WriteLine("is encoder " + info.IsEncoder);

                MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities;
                bool formatSupported;

                // does codec support this mime type
                try
                {
                    capabilities = info.GetCapabilitiesForType(mime);
                    System.Console.WriteLine("capabilities1 " + capabilities);
                    System.Console.WriteLine("capabilities2 " + capabilities.MimeType);
                    System.Console.WriteLine("capabilities3 " + capabilities.DefaultFormat);
                    System.Console.WriteLine("capabilities4 " + capabilities.EncoderCapabilities);
                }
                catch (Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException ignored)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // does codec support this video format
                try
                {
                    formatSupported = capabilities.IsFormatSupported(format);
                    System.Console.WriteLine("formatSupported " + formatSupported);

                    foreach (var color in capabilities.ColorFormats)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("supported color " + color);
                    }
                }
                catch (Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException ignored)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // can we configure it successfully
                if (formatSupported)
                {
                    // try decoder
                    try
                    {
                        codec = MediaCodec.CreateByCodecName(info.Name);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("codec " + info.Name);

                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Configuring");
                        codec.Configure(format, null, null, MediaCodecConfigFlags.Encode);
                    }
                    catch (Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException ignored)
                    {
                        // configure() failed
                        System.Console.WriteLine("ERROR WHILE CONFIGURING " + ignored.Message);
                        codec.Release();
                        continue;
                    }
                    catch (Java.Lang.IllegalStateException ignored)
                    {
                        // configure() failed
                        System.Console.WriteLine("ERROR STATE WHILE CONFIGURING " + ignored.Message);
                        codec.Release();
                        continue;
                    }
                    // configure() successful
                    return codec;
                }
            } // end of for loop

            // no decoder found
            System.Console.WriteLine("No encoder found");

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the ScreenShotService class it inherits:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using myApp.Droid;
using myApp.Interface;
using Android.Graphics;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ScreenshotService))]
namespace myApp.Droid
{
    public class ScreenshotService : IScreenshotService
    {
        

        public async Task<byte[]> Capture()
        {

            var _currentActivity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
             var rootView = _currentActivity.Window.DecorView.RootView;
             using (var screenshot = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(
                                     rootView.Width,
                                     rootView.Height,
                                     Bitmap.Config.Argb8888))
             {

                 var canvas = new Canvas(screenshot);

                 rootView.Draw(canvas);

                 using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                 {
                     screenshot.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 90, stream);
                     return stream.ToArray();
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate, as this is just out of my wheelhouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android 13? The same error was seen [in 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62004735/6309), and pointed out to [Xamarin Foreground Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services).

The 2020 answer involved creating an extension method to start the foreground service, handling Android 8.0 (Oreo) and higher differently from older versions using [`Context.StartForegroundService` and `Context.StartService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) respectively:

```cs
public static void StartForegroundServiceCompat<T>(this Context context, Bundle args = null) where T : Service
{
    var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(T));
    if (args != null) 
    {
        intent.PutExtras(args);
    }

    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        context.StartForegroundService(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        context.StartService(intent);
    }
}
```

Once started, register the service as a foreground service by invoking `StartForeground`, providing a unique ID and a `Notification` object:

```cs
public const int SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 10000;

public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    var notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name))
        .SetContentText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.notification_text))
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_name)
        .SetContentIntent(BuildIntentToShowMainActivity())
        .SetOngoing(true)
        .AddAction(BuildRestartTimerAction())
        .AddAction(BuildStopServiceAction())
        .Build();

    StartForeground(SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

To unregister, call `StopForeground` method (`StopForeground(true);`). It will not stop the service but will remove the notification icon, signaling Android that the service can be shut down if necessary:

---

In your case, add the following service declaration within the `<application>` tag:

```xml
<service android:name=".CameraService" android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection" android:exported="false" />
```

Declare a new **ServiceHelper.cs** file:

```cs
public static class ServiceHelper
{
    public static void StartForegroundServiceCompat<T>(this Context context, Bundle args = null) where T : Service
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(T));
        if (args != null)
        {
            intent.PutExtras(args);
        }

        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            context.StartForegroundService(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            context.StartService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**CameraService.cs**: The `CameraService` should inherit from `Android.App.Service` instead of `ScreenshotService`, in order to [create a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/).
Override `OnStartCommand` to call `StartForeground`.

```cs
public class CameraService : Android.App.Service
{
    public const int SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 10000;

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        var notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetContentTitle("Camera Service Running")
            .SetContentText("Tap to return to the app")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_name)  // Ensure you have this icon in your resources
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .Build();

        StartForeground(SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        // Add other necessary code
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

In your activity or wherever you want to start the `CameraService`, you would use the `ServiceHelper` class as follows:

```cs
ServiceHelper.StartForegroundServiceCompat<CameraService>(this);
```

---

As noted by [Trevor Balcom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186046/trevor-balcom) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77250760/xam-forms-app-with-mediaprojections-error-media-projections-require-a-foregroun/77263514?noredirect=1#comment136259043_77263514):

> There is an official [`ContextCompat.StartForegroundService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#startForegroundService(android.content.Context,android.content.Intent)) method in the AndroidX API now to handle launching foreground services on the various Android platforms.
>
> Since we're talking about Android 13, there are now permissions (POST_NOTIFICATIONS) required to show a notification. Xamarin.Essentials can be extended to support this. The notification API has also required setting up [notification channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough#create-the-notification-channel) since Android O.

The `ServiceHelper` class is simpler if it uses `ContextCompat.StartForegroundService` instead of `context.StartForegroundService`. It provides a compatibility wrapper around these methods to handle different Android versions without explicit version checking.

**ServiceHelper.cs**:

```cs
public static class ServiceHelper
{
    public static void StartForegroundServiceCompat<T>(this Context context, Bundle args = null) where T : Service
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(T));
        if (args != null) intent.PutExtras(args);

        ContextCompat.StartForegroundService(context, intent);
    }
}
```

And to comply with Android 13's new permission requirement for posting notifications, you would need to add the `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

Plus, you may need to request this permission at runtime using the Android permissions request framework.

Comment: There is an official `ContextCompat.StartForegroundService` method in the AndroidX API now to handle launching foreground services on the various Android platforms.

Comment: Since we're talking about Android 13, there are now permissions (`POST_NOTIFICATIONS`) required to show a notification. Xamarin.Essentials can be extended to support this. The notification API has also required setting up [notification channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough#create-the-notification-channel) since Android O.

Comment: @TrevorBalcom Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC I have an issue once I tell the foreground service to stop.  Any chance you can share your knowledge on this new question?  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609235/maui-error-screen-recording-error-on-stoprecording)