# Maui Error - Screen Recording - Error on StopRecording();

Tags: maui, foreground-service, maui-android

I'm working on attempting to add Android implementation to https://github.com/jfversluis/Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording

I think I checked all bases, but I'm getting this exception on MediaRecorder.Stop();

```
{Java.Lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod(JniObjectReference instance, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 20370
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod(String encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:line 66
   at Android.Media.MediaRecorder.Stop() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Android.Media.MediaRecorder.cs:line 2477
   at Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording.ScreenRecordingImplementation.StopRecording(ScreenRecordingOptions options) in D:\pmsr\src\Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording\ScreenRecording.android.cs:line 84
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace ---
java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
    at crc64fcf28c0e24b4cc31.ButtonHandler_ButtonClickListener.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at crc64fcf28c0e24b4cc31.ButtonHandler_ButtonClickListener.onClick(ButtonHandler_ButtonClickListener.java:31)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

  --- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace ---
java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
    at crc64fcf28c0e24b4cc31.ButtonHandler_ButtonClickListener.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at crc64fcf28c0e24b4cc31.ButtonHandler_ButtonClickListener.onClick(ButtonHandler_ButtonClickListener.java:31)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
}
```

I'm guessing it is something stupid I am looking over.  Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**ScreenRecording.android.cs**

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Media.Projection;
using Android.Hardware.Display;
using Android.Views;
using Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using AndroidX.Core.Graphics.Drawable;
using Microsoft.Maui.Devices;
using static Android.Provider.Telephony.Mms;
using Microsoft.Maui.Storage;



namespace Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording;

public partial class ScreenRecordingImplementation : IScreenRecording
{
    public MediaProjectionManager ProjectionManager;
    public MediaProjection MediaProjection;
    public VirtualDisplay VirtualDisplay;
    public MediaRecorder MediaRecorder;
    public string FilePath;
    public const int REQUEST_MEDIA_PROJECTION = 1;

    public static EventHandler<ScreenRecordingEventArgs> ScreenRecordingPermissionHandler;
    public ScreenRecordingImplementation()
    {
        ProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager)Platform.AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.MediaProjectionService);

        
    }

    public bool IsRecording { get; private set; }

    public bool IsSupported { get { return ProjectionManager != null; } private set { }}
    

    


    public async Task StartRecording(bool enableMicrophone)
    {
        if (IsSupported)
        {

            

            MediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            //FilePath = Path.Combine(Platform.AppContext.FilesDir.AbsolutePath, $"recording_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.mp4");

            FilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory, "Screen.mp4");

            SetUpMediaRecorder(enableMicrophone);
            try
            {

                await Task.Delay(2000);
                MediaRecorder.Start();
                IsRecording = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw new NotSupportedException("Screen recording did not start.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Screen recording not supported on this device.");
        }
    }

    public async Task<ScreenRecordingFile?> StopRecording(ScreenRecordingOptions? options)
    {
        if (IsRecording)
        {
            IsRecording = false;
            try
            {
                MediaRecorder.Stop();
                MediaRecorder.Release();
                VirtualDisplay.Release();
                MediaProjection.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            var context = Android.App.Application.Context;

            context.StopService(new Intent(context, typeof(ScreenRecordingService)));

            return new ScreenRecordingFile(FilePath);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public async void OnScreenCapturePermissionGranted(Result resultCode, Intent? data)
    {
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok && data != null)
        {
            var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(ScreenRecordingService));
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                context.StartForegroundService(serviceIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                context.StartService(serviceIntent);
            }

            await Task.Delay(2000);

            // Handle the successful permission result
            MediaProjection mediaProjection = ProjectionManager.GetMediaProjection((int)resultCode, data);

            VirtualDisplay = mediaProjection.CreateVirtualDisplay("Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording.ScreenRecordingImplementation.ScreenRecordingService", (int)DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width, (int)DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Height, (int)DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Density, Android.Views.DisplayFlags.Presentation, null, null, null);

        }
        else
        {
            // Handle the case where permission was not granted
        }
        // Additional setup or start recording
    }

    public void SetUpMediaRecorder(bool enableMicrophone)
    {
        MediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        if (enableMicrophone)
        {
            MediaRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
        }

        MediaRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Surface);
        MediaRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);
        MediaRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);

        if (enableMicrophone)
        {
            MediaRecorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AmrNb);
        }

        MediaRecorder.SetOutputFile(FilePath);
        MediaRecorder.SetVideoSize((int)DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width, (int)DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Height);
        MediaRecorder.SetVideoFrameRate(30);

        try
        {
            MediaRecorder.Prepare();
        }
        catch (Java.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MediaRecorder preparation failed: {ex.Message}");
            // Handle preparation failure
            MediaRecorder.Release();
        }
    }

    public void Setup()
    {
        Intent captureIntent = ProjectionManager.CreateScreenCaptureIntent();
        Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivityForResult(captureIntent, REQUEST_MEDIA_PROJECTION);
    }

    public class ScreenRecordingEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Result ResultCode { get; set; }

        public Intent? Data { get; set; }
    }

    [Service(ForegroundServiceType = ForegroundService.TypeMediaProjection)]
    public class ScreenRecordingService : Service
    {
        public override IBinder? OnBind(Intent? intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent? intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            string CHANNEL_ID = "ScreenRecordingService";
            int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1337;

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                var channelName = "Screen Recording Service";
                var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationImportance.Default)
                {
                    Description = "Notification Channel for Screen Recording Service"
                };

                var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
                notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            // Create a notification for the foreground service
            var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .SetContentTitle("Screen Recording")
                .SetContentText("Recording screen...")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification_template_icon_low_bg); // Ensure you have 'ic_notification' in Resources/drawable

            var notification = notificationBuilder.Build();

            // Start the service in the foreground
            StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording;

namespace ScreenRecordingSample;

[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    public const int REQUEST_MEDIA_PROJECTION = 1;
    ScreenRecordingImplementation screenRecordingImplementation = new ScreenRecordingImplementation();


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize other components...

        // Initialize ScreenRecordingImplementation
        screenRecordingImplementation = new Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording.ScreenRecordingImplementation();
    }
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent? data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_MEDIA_PROJECTION)
        {
            screenRecordingImplementation.OnScreenCapturePermissionGranted(resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <service android:name="Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording.ScreenRecordingImplementation.ScreenRecordingService" android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-sdk />    
</manifest>
```

**IScreenRecording.cs**

```
namespace Plugin.Maui.ScreenRecording;

/// <summary>
/// Provides the ability to record the screen within your app.
/// </summary>
public interface IScreenRecording
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets whether or not screen recording is currently happening.
    /// </summary>
    bool IsRecording { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets whether or not screen recording is supported on this device.
    /// </summary>
    bool IsSupported { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets up the screenrecording.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This is needed for android to request media projection.
    /// </remarks>
    void Setup();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the screenrecording.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enableMicrophone">Determines if the microphone should be used as input during the recording.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Task"/> object with information about this operation.</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// A permission to access the microphone might be needed, this is not requested by this method.
    /// Make sure to add an entry in the metadata of your app and request the runtime permission
    /// before calling this method.
    /// </remarks>
    Task StartRecording(bool enableMicrophone);

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the recording and saves the video file to the device's gallery.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Task"/> object with information about this operation.</returns>
    Task<ScreenRecordingFile?> StopRecording(ScreenRecordingOptions? options = null);
}
```

The rest of the code is the same as the main repository I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, surround the [`MediaRecorder.Stop()` call](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#stop()) with a try-catch block to handle any runtime exceptions gracefully. That will not solve the root cause but can prevent the app from crashing.

```java
try
{
    MediaRecorder.Stop();
}
catch (Java.Lang.RuntimeException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error stopping MediaRecorder: " + ex.Message);
    // Handle the exception, e.g., by logging
}
```

The `MediaRecorder.Stop()` method will fail if the recording has not actually started or if it is already stopped. Make sure `MediaRecorder.Start()` is successfully called before invoking `Stop()`.

```java
if (IsRecording)
{
    // Proceed to stop the recording
}
```

The [`MediaRecorder` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) is also very sensitive to the order of method calls. Make sure that the sequence of `Prepare()`, `Start()`, and `Stop()` calls is correct. You must call `Prepare()` before `Start()`, and `Start()` must have enough time to initiate the recording before you call `Stop()`.

If the recording is stopped immediately after it starts, the `MediaRecorder` might not have enough data to finalize the video file, leading to this exception. Introduce a delay between start and stop to make sure some data is recorded.

```java
// Wait for a minimum duration before allowing stop
if ((DateTime.UtcNow - recordingStartTime).TotalSeconds < MIN_RECORDING_DURATION)
{
    // Wait or notify the user
}
```

After stopping the recording, make sure resources are released properly. Call `MediaRecorder.Release()` after `MediaRecorder.Stop()`. Also, release the `VirtualDisplay` and `MediaProjection` objects.

---

> The issue is the `MediaProjectionManager` and Virtual display are null once I got to the code since they aren't using the same instance, so I believe I have to DI so they are the same, right?

True, you should use the DI container to resolve your `IScreenRecording` instance.
But, as you have discovered, injecting dependencies directly into the `MainActivity` constructor is not straightforward because Android requires a default constructor for activities.

A possible workaround would, instead of using constructor injection, to use property or method injection mentioned in "[Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection)". That can be done after the activity is created and its dependencies are ready to be injected.

The article "[Are you using Dependency Injection in your .NET MAUI app yet?](https://blog.ewers-peters.de/are-you-using-dependency-injection-in-your-net-maui-app-yet)" from [Julian Ewers-Peters](https://hashnode.com/@ewerspej) mentions "[service locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern)" to resolve dependencies (examples in "[Page Resolver and Navigation Extension for MAUI](https://goforgoldman.com/posts/maui-page-resolver/)" from [Matt Goldman](https://goforgoldman.com/about/)), but cautions

> I am aware that the ServiceHelper is an implementation of the Service Locator pattern, which is often regarded as an anti-pattern. However, in certain scenarios, especially with regards to .NET-baseed UI technologies, the Service Locator pattern is a necessity.

But a commonly used workaround would be to resolve the dependency in the `OnCreate` method (see "[.NET MAUI / App lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle?view=net-maui-8.0)") of your `MainActivity`. That makes sure the dependency is resolved as soon as the activity is created, but before it is used.

For that last approach, your `MainActivity` using DI for `IScreenRecording` would be:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; // Make sure you have this using directive

namespace ScreenRecordingSample;

[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    private IScreenRecording screenRecordingImplementation;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Resolve IScreenRecording using the DI container
        screenRecordingImplementation = MauiApplication.Current.Services.GetService<IScreenRecording>();

        // Rest of the OnCreate implementation
    }

    // Rest of your MainActivity code
}
```

Comment: after going crazy debugging I think I see the issue, however I am not sure how to fix it.   

The app is using DI to inject the ScreenRecording:
`builder.Services.AddSingleton<IScreenRecording, ScreenRecordingImplementation>();`

However the mainActivity is creating a new class at startup.  I tried to just inject by adding to the default contructor:

`public MainActivity (IScreenRecording screenRecording)
{
 screenRecordingImplementation = screenRecording;
}`

But it won't compile without a default constructor.  So I added it but only the default constructor gets called.

Comment: Didn't have enough room, but the issue is the MediaProjectionManager and Virtual display are null once I got to the code since they aren't using the same instance, so I believe I have to DI so they are the same right?

Comment: @berr08 Right. I have edited the answer to address your comment.